# Java, Selenium, IntelliJ - cannot use the variable from DataFile.properties

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

as you can see on the screen, I wouldn't like to hardcode the URL link and I would like to use the variable from the DataFile.properties.

Other variable "browser" is used from this file and it works correctly, however when it comes to URL link, I get the NullPointerException.

Could anyone have a look at the issue and explain why it is like this?
I did the same steps as in the tutorial and it doesn't work for me.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtOqm.png)
[updated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4kQN.png)

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new Properties variable in your 'initrializeDriver()' method, which isn't the same variable that's part of the Base class. It will only exist in the method and will be destroyed when the method finishes.

The `properties` field that you're trying to access in the ValidateTitle class hasn't actually been initialised yet, so that's where the NullPointerException is coming from.

If you change the following line in Base.java

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
```

to

```
this.properties = new Properties();
```

it should work for the 'link' property as well.

Comment: Hello, I've updated as you suggested, however this time I got other exception: Invalid argument..

Comment: Try removing the quotation marks from the link property